# How can i add an image to an existing zip folder of static resource using apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, metadata-api, metadata, static-resources

How can i add an image to an existing zip folder of static resource using apex class.
Basically, the requirement is that, whenever i upload an image using my custom image uploader component, the image should get added to one of my existing folders.

Comment: There is no built-in ZIP handling in Apex and whilst I have found an Apex-based implementation the problem is the CPU time required to perform ZIP operations is prohibitive. You will face governor limits troubles. Additionally, this is not how static resources are intended to work and there's no Apex API for managing this metadata. You should use files and content versions instead.

Comment: But via things like Zippex ( https://github.com/pdalcol/Zippex) and apex mdapi (https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) it might be possible in theory. But that would require lots of time, and will ont indeed be stable solution as mentioned by @PhilW